# "column must appear in the GROUP BY clause" when using date_trunc on timestamps

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an SQL query which counts contacts with given create date. Create date is stored as unix timestamp in miliseconds and I'm using `to_timestamp` method to format it correctly:

```
SELECT count(*) AS "Count", date_trunc('month', to_timestamp("contacts"."createdate"::double precision / 1000)) AS "Create Date"
FROM "contacts"
GROUP BY "contacts"."createdate"
ORDER BY "contacts"."createdate" ASC
```

Results are as following:

```
Count | Create Date
-----------------------------------------
1     | Sunday, February 1, 2015 12:00 AM
1     | Sunday, February 1, 2015 12:00 AM
1     | Wednesday, April 1, 2015 12:00 AM
1     | Wednesday, April 1, 2015 12:00 AM
1     | Wednesday, April 1, 2015 12:00 AM
```

I'd like to group them by month, so for the example above I would like to have:

```
Count | Create Date
-----------------------------------------
2     | February 2015
3     | April 2015
```

I change SQL to the following:

```
SELECT count(*) AS "Count", date_trunc('month', to_timestamp("contacts"."createdate"::double precision / 1000)) AS "Create Date"
FROM "contacts"
GROUP BY date_trunc('month', to_timestamp("contacts"."createdate"::double precision / 1000))
ORDER BY "contacts"."createdate" ASC
```

But receive an error:

```
ERROR: column "contacts.createdate" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Is there any way I can do it properly?

Comment: It is because of `ORDER BY "contacts"."createdate" ASC`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to elements from your SELECT by number:

```
SELECT count(*) AS "Count", date_trunc('month', to_timestamp("contacts"."createdate"::double precision / 1000)) AS "Create Date"
FROM "contacts"
GROUP BY date_trunc('month', to_timestamp("contacts"."createdate"::double precision / 1000))
ORDER BY 2 ASC
```

Comment: Or even simpler `group by 2 order by 2 asc`

Comment: That worked, thanks @l-o-van-ingen! Any tips on how to display that in "Month YYYY" format?
When using `to_char(timestamp, 'Month YYYY')` i get: 

 - April 2015
 - April 2016
 - April 2017
 - May 2015
 - May 2016

etc

Comment: Check [9.8. Data Type Formatting Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html) in the postgresql documentation. It might even be that an appropriate `to_char` allows you to get rid of your current `date_trunc`... Something like `SELECT count(*) AS "Count", to_char("contacts"."createdate", 'Month YYYY') AS "Create Date"`...